# Creating a button based on user input

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

I have a website where you can enter information into an `input` box and then below it a `button` that says "add". When pushing this `button` I want it to create a new `button` with the text inputted above.

I'm not quite sure even where to start with the javascript but here's my `html`:

```
<input type="text" name="device" id="device">
<button class="add">Add</button>\
```

I'm just trying to make an add `button` make another `button` with the text in `input` box above.

Comment: Hi Max and welcome to SO. Sure we can help you with it. Share the HTML and JavaScript relevant to your question. We do expect you to make an attempt at figuring it out yourself. That way we can help you figure out how to fix your solution instead of building it for you. Show us what you got and we'll help you out.

Comment: I dont have any javascript at the moment because im not quite sure where to start but Ill edit in the html right now. If you could just give me some pointers im not asking anyone to write it for me.

Comment: Max, what exactly do you want the button to do? Do you want the text on the button to be what was inputted? and then what should happen when you press the new button?

Comment: Id like to click the button and then have another button appear on screen with the text that was inputted by the user above

Comment: I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: Max, when the button appears with the inputted text what do you want it to do when you click on it?

Comment: My end goal is to have 2 places to input text one a website and the other the button name. When adding the button with the add button below I want it to create the button with the name that was inputted and when the new button is clicked I want it to take you to the website submitted.

Comment: I also want to be able to create multiple buttons rather then just one.

Answer (score 0):

### Concepts

You need to change the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) and append a new [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) to your HTML.

To do this you need to capture the value when you click on the button and, after that, render the new element. I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorlucss/pen/yLMQmrM) to help you with that:

To explain:

**HTML**

```
<input id="my-input" placeholder="Place your text here" />

<button id="my-button">Submit</button>

<p id="my-content"></p>
```

Every element has an `id` that you'll use on your...

**Javascript:**

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('my-input')
const myButton = document.getElementById('my-button')
const content = document.getElementById('my-content')

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  
  const myInputValue = myInput.value;
  
  content.innerHTML = myInputValue
})
```

By first we get all elements on DOM using `document.getElementById` function. After that we add an event to our button, the event of click. After that, we catch the value inputted by the user and change the HTML inner our `p` tag and put the text that have been inputted in our `input`.

So, after that, the text will be rendered on the screen and you can see what you have inputted.

[image]

### Soluctions

By now, using this concept, we can now use this and change also, in our element, the style of showing or not. You can follow to [this other Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorlucss/pen/eYvbOpy) that I'll use in our example:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="my-input" placeholder="Place your text here" />

<button id="my-button">Submit</button>

<button id="my-other-button"></button>
```

**Javascript**

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('my-input')
const myButton = document.getElementById('my-button')
const myOtherButton = document.getElementById('my-other-button')

myOtherButton.style.display = 'none'

myButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  
  const myInputValue = myInput.value;
  
  myOtherButton.style.display = 'block'
  
  myOtherButton.innerHTML = myInputValue
})
```

So, now we are capturing our elements as before, but that time we capture also an empty button and, with `style.display` property we change, when the first render occurs, to not showing our button. After we click in the first button we change it again to show it and, as before, change the innerHTML with the text that user have inputted.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate this a lot but is there anyway I can make the result instead of just text an actual button? Id like to also be able to click the button and make it take you somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you can! Using this concepts you can access others parameters of your HTML element, like showing or not showing your content (in your case, a button). I'll edit the answer so can help you more.

Comment: Done, @MaxSinger. Hope this helps you!  :)

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful but Im noticing If I try and add another button it just edits the existing one can I make it so it creates more buttons instead of editing the existing one or is that not possible? Thanks, Max

Comment: This is possible by manipulating the DOM and creating programmatically a button. This isn't too simple as we did in our thread, you will need to know more about [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [HTML Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node) concepts. I did that on [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/victorlucss/pen/BaWvBVp)

Comment: Okay, Is it also possible to make the new button have a link attached to it so when its clicked it takes you to a certain website that is also inputted before the creation of the button?

Comment: Yes, Is possible. You only will need to attach an event listener to your new button. I also did that on [this pen](https://codepen.io/victorlucss/pen/BaWvBVp)